# What are the repercussions of redefining access modifiers?

Tags: c++

What would be some possible repercussions of redefining C++ access modifiers via preprocessed commands for the sake of inducing C#/Java like syntax?

```
#include <iostream>

// The access modifiers are redefined here.
#define public public:
#define protected protected:
#define private private:

class Halo
{
    public Halo(int xx)
    {
        x = xx;
    }

    public int getX()
    {
        return x;
    }

    private int x;
};

int main()
{
    Halo* halo = new Halo(3);

    std::cout << halo->getX();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: One would be undefined behaviour. I'm pretty sure it says somewhere in the standard that redefining a keyword is.

Comment: #1 Redefining keywords is (IIRC, arguably) undefined behavior. #2 This isn't Java or C#, get used to it.

Comment: C++ is not Java. One subtle issue that you encounter here is inline functions. You should learn about how these work so that you can use them intentionally when appropriate.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
class B : public A {};
```

> `expected '{' before ':' token`
>   `expected unqualified-id before ':' token`
>   `expected class-name before ':' token`

Answer (score 3):

Aside from the already mentioned consequence of syntax errors. 
Doing this would get other people confused. A long time ago, people would program in Pascal, and then when moving to C use `#define BEGIN {` and `#define END }`, which led to code that sort of looked like pascal, but of course wasn't at all like pascal in many other ways.

You are programming in a different language. So why pretend that it isn't.

I guess it's because you think it's Java that you forgot to delete your halo object as well?

Answer (score 2):

Anything could happen as redefining a language keyword is undefined behavior.

Generally speaking you should write idiomatic code for the language you're using. If you want to use Java/C# syntax just write your code in those languages.